# python-ldap: How to fix b'ldapadd: invalid format (line 1) entry: ""\n'

Tags: python, testing, ldap, python-ldap, ldif

I want to create an ldap test server. So I dumped the ldap data with `ldapsearch` and created a `.ldif` file Now I want to create a test ldap server with this data. I want to use the [`slapdtest`-module](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/reference/slapdtest.html) from `python-ldap`.

```
import slapdtest

with slapdtest.SlapdObject() as server:

    server.ldapadd("ldap_dump.ldif")
    server.start()
```

But I get the error message:

```
RuntimeError: ['/usr/bin/ldapadd', '-H', 'ldapi://../python-ldap-test-53974/ldapi', '-Y', 'EXTERNAL', '-Q', '-n'] process failed:
b''
b'ldapadd: invalid format (line 1) entry: ""\n'
```

`$file ldap_dump.ldif` returns `ldap_dump.ldif: ASCII text`. So the line endings shouldn't be a problem actually.

This is my reduced ldap_dump file:

```
dn: cn=User,dc=institute.edu
sn: User
objectClass: top
objectClass: user
cn: User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of your error is that the `ldapadd` method expects to receive LDIF-format content, but you are passing it a filename. So you want something more like:

```
with slapdtest.SlapdObject() as server:
    with open('ldap_dump.ldif') as fd:
      server.ldapadd(fd.read())
```

You seem to be calling `server.start()` *after* `ldapadd`, and I think you need those lines in the reverse order.

Lastly, your sample file is probably invalid because it doesn't define the higher-level containers (e.g., `dc=institute.edu`) to contain the objects described in your example.